Delphi textlayout.textwidth and textheight not working, why?
I'm trying to learn how to use TTextLayout object to add some special characters to my graphic drawings.
Unfortunately this object seems having some special behaviours that seem not documented in Delphi help docs and on Embarcadero online docs.
I have derived the following code from the Delphi code examples adding some features that I need to use.
Teese features are the usage of TextWidth and TextHeight to obtain the width and height of the characters to be drawn.
For convenience I have replaced the font I'm using with the Arial font.
I have added some buttons to enlarge/reduce the size of the character, and some other buttons to choose different characters. Well, when the character changes, and when the size changes, nothing seems to change in width and height of the TTextLayout object. The values of width and height of the object seem remain the same.
I have tried whatever came to my mind, putting before or after each single statement, but nothing. The Width and Height of the TTextLayout seem remain the same.
What I'm doing wrong? What is it that I'm not understanding correctly?
Thankyou for your kind help, as usual.
unit MainGraphicText;
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Objects,FMX.TextLayout, FMX.Edit;

type
  TMainFormGraphicText = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Width: TEdit;
    Height: TEdit;
    DimLess: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    DimMore: TButton;
    Label2: TLabel;
    ShowDim: TEdit;
    ShowChar: TEdit;
    CharLess: TButton;
    CharMore: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Image1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
    procedure DimLessClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DimMoreClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CharLessClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CharMoreClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
     WhichChar : Integer;
     Dimension : Single;
     MyRect : TRectF;
  end;

var
  MainFormGraphicText: TMainFormGraphicText;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}


procedure TMainFormGraphicText.CharMoreClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   WhichChar := WhichChar + 1;
   if WhichChar > 80 then
      WhichChar := 80;
   ShowChar.Text := WhichChar.ToString;
   Image1.Repaint;
end;

procedure TMainFormGraphicText.CharLessClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   WhichChar := WhichChar - 1;
   if WhichChar < 1 then
      WhichChar := 1;
   ShowChar.Text := WhichChar.ToString;
   Image1.Repaint;
end;

procedure TMainFormGraphicText.DimLessClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Dimension := Dimension - 1;
   if Dimension < 9 then
      Dimension := 9;
   ShowDim.Text := Dimension.ToString;
   Image1.Repaint;
end;

procedure TMainFormGraphicText.DimMoreClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Dimension := Dimension + 1;
   if Dimension > 72 then
      Dimension := 72;
   ShowDim.Text := Dimension.ToString;
   Image1.Repaint;
end;

procedure TMainFormGraphicText.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   WhichChar := 40;
   Dimension := 48;
   MyRect := TRect.Create(TPoint.Create(0, 0),Trunc(Image1.Width),Trunc(Image1.Height));
   Canvas.BeginScene;
   Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
   Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
   Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 1.0;
   Canvas.DrawRect(MyRect,1);
   Canvas.EndScene;
end;

procedure TMainFormGraphicText.Image1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
Const Acapo = '#13#10';
var
  WPosition: Integer;
  W,H : Single;
  MyLayout: TTextLayout;
begin

  Canvas.BeginScene;
  Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
  Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
  Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 1.0;
  Canvas.DrawRect(MyRect,1);
  Canvas.EndScene;
  MyLayout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
  MyLayout.BeginUpdate;
  MyLayout.TopLeft := TPointF.Create(0, 0);
  MyLayout.Font.Family := 'Arial'; // 'Delfos2';
  MyLayout.Font.Size := Dimension;
  MyLayout.Font.Style := [];
  MyLayout.Trimming := TTextTrimming.Character;
  MyLayout.Text := chr(63 + WhichChar); // Copy(Aspetti_Delfos2,WhichChar,1);
  MyLayout.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Brown;
  ShowDim.Text := MyLayout.Font.Size.ToString;
  ShowChar.Text := WhichChar.ToString;
  WPosition := MyLayout.PositionAtPoint(TPointF.Create(0, 0));
  Width.Text := MyLayout.TextWidth.ToString;
  Height.Text := MyLayout.TextHeight.ToString;
  MyLayout.EndUpdate;
  MyLayout.RenderLayout(Canvas);
  MyLayout.Free;
end;
end.

@SilverWarrior:
I have tried the modifications you have proposed, but it seems they're not working at all.
Particularly, I tried what follows:
  MyLayout.EndUpdate;
  MyLayout.RenderLayout(Canvas);

   Width.Text := MyLayout.TextWidth.ToString;
  Height.Text := MyLayout.TextHeight.ToString;

Logics say that only after the rendition of MyLayout the object knows the data of the changed text, but it is not.
The data inside the two TEdit shows the same value than before.

The fact of seeing updates only in case of INVALIDATION made me think. What if the problem was limited only to updating the video fields but the true dimension values were updated correctly?
I added saving the dimensional values in memory and highlighted them when exiting the program to see if that was true and it is.
The various text dimension values are updated. Only the value in TEdit fields is not. To update these values you need to call INVALIDATE, but not to know the true value of the TTextLayout dimensions, which are updated correctly.

Is this a solution? Please clarify your answer because it's very difficult to understand how this resolved the problem

You are calling your code for retrieving text dimensions a bit to fast. Since you previously called MyLayout.BeginUpdate; you prevent any changes to your Text Layout to take affect before MyLayout.EndUpdate; is called.
Main use of this is to avoid to frequent updates. But it also affects some own properties of Text Layout to be updated including the TextWidth and TextHeight.
So make sure your MyLayout.EndUpdate; is before retrieving Text Width and Text Height and your code will work as expected.
MyLayout.EndUpdate;
Width.Text := MyLayout.TextWidth.ToString;
Height.Text := MyLayout.TextHeight.ToString;


EDIT: After scratching my head for quite some time I noticed something strange. When changing properties of other components from within Image1Paint thy are not always updated or only partially updated. But I'm not exactly sure why.
I'm guessing it might even be bad practice of trying to update other controls from within the paint method of yours as it could lead to race condition when painting.
Workaround for this is to call MainFormGraphicText.Invalidate; at the end of Image1Paint procedure. This forces all controls on the form to fully update. But as noted before this might be bad practice.

Unfortunately it seems not working.
While the characters change in the rendition, the dimensions remain unchanged.
Really weird.
How can I add code to the comments? I'd like to post another variation but it is not formatted correctly. Is it possible?

@SergioBonfiglio You can't add code to comments. Instead you should edit the question with additional information.

OK, got it. I edited the original post.

@SergioBonfiglio I have updated my answer with a cause and potential workaround for your problems. But you may want to rethink your design a bit.

It seems that adding INVALIDATE at the end of the paint procedure the program works. But I have two questions.

What do you mean with "race conditions"
You say that I have to "rethink" my design. But the problem is that I need to get the text dimensions, because it is part of the main program. It is required to correctly position the characters inside other drawing. So how should I retrieve these dimensions using different procedures instead of those used in the example?
Thankyou for your kind support.


What I was thinking about redesign is to refactor your code in a way so that TTextLayout is not created and freed within the scope of OnPaint event but instead it is created and destroyed along with the control on which you will use it. Main advantage would be to avoid the overhead of constantly creating and freeing TTextLayout on each paint. Another main advanteage that would come usefull to you is the ability to modify or retrieve TTextLayout information outside OnPaint event. Not to mention that you would be only modifying relevant data and not all the data all the time. ...

... And of course it will avoid you the need to update other controls from within OnPaint event of one control which is what is causing your problems no. Also you could potentially create multiple instances of TTextLayout and then just chose which one you want to use at specific time.

Also in your comment you say that you need to position this character inside other drawings. Are perhaps you talking here about positioning of this characters in relative position of some other text? If so then I suggest you check Learn To Add Custom Text Rendering And Formatting Capabilities To Your Delphi FMX Controls Quickly article where author uses Text Layout Attributes to change only specific parts of the text.
